# Error: unexpected update count received (Actual: 0, Expected 1)

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a table and now find that when I try and delete a row or change a field, I get the following message:

> Unexpected update count received (Actual: 0, Expected: 1). All changes will be rolled back.

I saw another question about this that said to create a unique field and try again. I dropped the table, recreated it with a unique field and am still getting the same error.

The code to create the table is:

```
create table 'transcribercertifications' (
   id int(11) not null unique auto_increment,
   tid int(11) not null,
   certId varchar(32) not null,
   regNum int(11) not null,
   expiration date
);
```

I have been deleting and updating 'by hand' in PhpStorm. Any help fixing this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please show the code that is doing the update /throwing the error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to make your `id` column as a primary key. Try this one:

```
create table 'transcribercertifications' (
   id int(11) not null primary key auto_increment,
   tid int(11) not null,
   certId varchar(32) not null,
   regNum int(11) not null,
   expiration date
);
```

Comment: It worked for me too, but can you explain why this is needed?